# Data recovery on working hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

So I have a 5 bay hot swap SATA enclosure that's connected to a Silicon Image-based SATA adapter in a computer. It's running XP Pro. There are two 1.5TB hard drives in slots 1 and 2 respectively, set up using RAID 1 using the the Silicon Image utility. There are also two 1TB drives in bays 3 and 4, also set to RAID 1 the same way. The partitions for both RAID arrays are Dynamic partitions.

A few days back, there was a bare hard drive that needed some files copied off of, so it was popped it in bay 5, that bay to pass-through, and the copied data off of it. Later, I noticed that my 1.5TB drives no longer showed up in windows. In the Silicon Image utility, the drives showed up fine, no error. However, in Device Manager, it shows the RAID 1 array as uninitialized. It shows up as the right size, etc., but nothing else.

There's no sign of anything wrong with either drive, so I'm not sure what happened exactly. I'm not the only one who has access to that computer, so it is possible there is something else done to it that I don't know of. There's quite a lot of data on it still, and if at all possible, I'd prefer to not send it to Ontrack.

Does anyone know of software that would restore the partitions, keeping in mind that it's a Windows LDM partition? I have access to a variety of Operating Systems, so something that would work on Mac, Windows or Linux would be acceptable. The programs I usually use are not compatible with LDM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my 2 favorite programs for emergencies like this:

[**EaseUs Data Recovery Wizard**](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-software/) Free

[**WinHex**](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/index-m.html) Paid

Answer (score 1):

I suggest these:

> 1. [Handy Recovery](http://www.handyrecovery.com/)
> 2. [Free Data Recovery](http://free-backup.info/data-recovery-software.htm)
> 3. [Data Recovery Software](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/)