# Free hard drive recovery software

Tags: windows, hard-drive, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover harddrive data](https://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data)

Is there any free (preferably open source) hard drive recovery software for windows? I have taken the hard drive out  of an old laptop and have connected it via usb to my pc.

Comment: this has been asked numerous times: http://superuser.com/questions/87679/recover-data-from-hard-drive-with-partitions-but-not-most-data-overwritten and http://superuser.com/questions/31779/data-recovery-on-working-hard-drive and http://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For free software, I would suggest [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) which is available on [Ninite](http://ninite.com/).

I would recommend Ninite as it skips out the toolbar. You can deselect it during installation, but Ninite takes all the trouble away!

Comment: great software!