# Data recovery after hard disk format

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, backup, data-recovery

I had an HP Pavilion 13 a113cl and some months ago, about march or february, I installed Windows 10 Home Insider Preview on the computer. It was going fine until I realized that it did not support hardware virtualization which I needed for my android app development. So, I took a backup of the drive using AOMEI Backupper and stored it on my external hard drive. Then, I booted from my Windows 8.1 installation usb and deleted my hard drive, using the clean option in diskpart. Then I formatted the drive into NTFS and installed Windows 8.1 onto the drive. Everything was going fine until AOMEI Backupper would not let me restore from my backed up .adi files. It gives me the error: Element not found or image file not found. I tried everything but I could not get it to work. I need help on recovering my deleted hard drive data. Please help.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data recovery on working hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/31779/data-recovery-on-working-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the problem is with the AOMEI Backupper, but I would consider professional help for this one. They would be your best bet for getting back the best recovery of your data due to the overwrite damage from the fresh Windows installation. Most offer no-obligation evaluations.

Otherwise, you are likely going to need to use a separate working computer, and a software file recovery tool, and it may not be as clean of a recovery as you'd like. The file recovery tool will work from definitions of files it can detect in raw data, so you should be able to get back a lot, though you may lose filenames and directory structure. If you do this, make a clone first to be extra safe you don't cause more damage and remove other options.

If you used the [[all] options with the DiskPart clean command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), then according to the documentation, you might have overwritten all the data with zeroes. If that's really the case, you won't have any luck with your disk then, and you'll have to work on getting the AOMEI backup to work, possibly contacting the software vendor.

I wish you luck!